# Attempt to call a userdata value

Tags: lua, roblox, lua-userdata

So i'm trying to make a part disapear when the player touch it but it says : `Workspace.RedCastle.Grid.Script:1: attempt to call a userdata value`

Here's my code :

```
script.Parent.Part.Touched(function(part)
    for i, part in pairs(script.Parent.Parts:GetChildren()) do
        part.CanCollide = false
        part.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(5)
    for i, part in pairs(script.Parent.Parts:GetChildren()) do
        part.CanCollide = true
        part.Transparency = 0
    end
end)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: May be you mean `Touched:Connect()` instead of `Touched()`?

Comment: Thank's i didn't realized my error sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
script.Parent.Part.Touched:Connect(function(part)
    for i, part in pairs(script.Parent.Parts:GetChildren()) do
        part.CanCollide = false
        part.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(5)
    for i, part in pairs(script.Parent.Parts:GetChildren()) do
        part.CanCollide = true
        part.Transparency = 0
    end
end)
```